# Additive properties in CSS

Tags: css

I know in vanilla CSS, there is no way to create "additive" properties. What I mean by that is:

```
.shade {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.1);
}

<div class="shade">I have .1 black background</div>
<div class="shade shade shade">I also have .1 black background, but wouldn't it be cool if i had .3?</div>
```

What I hope to do is to avoid having to generate styles in a loop in order to multiply the opacity of a background shade and without having to specify a class for each one, because i don't know how many there are.

I suspect this isnt possible because it kind of defeats the purpose of the "C" in "CSS", and that's fine - but figured I'd ask in case somebody smarter than me knew of a way.

And I'd rather not do:

```
<div class="shade">
   <div class="shade">
     <div class="shade">
       No please
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why don't you just add a different class for it? and set it to be .3 opacity?

Comment: @Teknotica He specifically mentioned he wanted to avoid doing that.

Comment: This isn't possible in CSS, but you might be able to accomplish it with Javascript.

Comment: Yeah - I have it working now in JS, but wasn't sure if CSS had some magic baked in to newer specs or what.

Comment: In JS, by the way, it's just style="background: rgba(0,0,0,{{$index*.1}})" (using Angular)

Comment: No, but you might want to look at CSS preprocessors like [LESS](http://lesscss.org) or [Sass](http://sass-lang.com), which allow you to do things in the stylesheet like declare a colour variable: `@trans-black: rgba(0,0,0,.1)`, then use either `colour: @trans-black` or a use a function like `colour: fadein(@trans-black, 30%)`, which would generate a colour 30% less transparent (that example is in LESS; there similar functions in Sass, I believe.) Doesn't entirely address your problem, but it means you can generate shades in advance, and only change one line of CSS to change the base colour.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with JQuery **[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/aKVm6/)**

```
$("div").each(function(index){
    var classList = $(this).attr('class').split(/\s+/);
    var num = 0;
    $.each( classList, function(index, item){
        if (item === 'shade') {
            num = num + 0.1;
        }
    })
    $(this).css("background", "rgba(0,0,0," + num + ")");
 });
```

HTML:

```
<div class="shade">I have .1 black background</div>
<div class="shade shade other shade">I also have .1 black background, but wouldn't it be cool if i had .3?</div>
<div class="shade shade shade shade shade">0.5 opacity</div>
```